# How to make borders of images equal in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, jpg, borders

I'm throwing together a newsletter in InDesign that requires linking JPG images. It looks fine in InDesign but when I export the image to Adobe reader the borders on my images change so that one side is darker/thicker than the rest of the sides. I hope that makes sense. I need all my borders to match.

I've tried replacing the images, making the images bigger/smaller, basically the side that has the thicker border just jumps to a different side with any change that I've tried so far.

Comment: I'm afraid a screen shot of the issue may be needed.

Comment: It sounds as if the resolution of these images is higher than the threshold set in your PDF export settings, and so they get downsampled. Check what their *actual* ppi values are.

Comment: @Jongware Please provide answers using the answer form, so they can be a permanent part of the system, searchable, voteable, acceptable, and so forth.

Comment: @BESW: it's just something to check for the OP - not sure it *is* the problem. Anyway, I'm not in the mood for answering. Somehow the world seems a little bit less flat to-day.

Comment: Ashley, there really isn't enough information here for anyone to give you more than a guess. Perhaps you could expand the question and provide a couple of screenshots to make it clear what you're trying to solve.

Comment: Trapping issue? And how do you create your borders? In InDesign or on the JPG? And as everybody already mentioned, a screenshot would really help.

Comment: This is speculation without a screenshot, but if the border thickness changes with zoom level, and printing looks fine, this is an error in how Reader interprets post-script/vector to pixel/display.

Comment: For this correction you can adjust this files Brightness or Contrast. Click (Ctrl+M) then adjust your accurate look. Thanks.

Comment: It's not even clear whether the borders in question are part of the images or (vector) borders added in InDesign. Far too vague and unclear to be answerable.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a guess that the "borders" are actually part of the linked jpg....

**Remove** the borders from the jpg images.

**Add** your borders in InDesign to the image frames.

After this, the borders will be consistent.

Option #B.... ensure *every* linked jpg is at 100% scale in the InDesign document. It's probable that some of the linked images have been scaled. If the borders *are* part of the actual jpgs... scaling the linked image in InDesign *will* alter the border widths.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably a pdf issue. I would export the entire InDesign file as a hi-res jpeg and then convert that/those jpeg(s) to a pdf.

Comment: No luck, it changed which lines were thicker but still the same issue. Thanks, anyway!

Comment: Hi @Ashley you can edit your question to add what you have tried, give us some screenshots; that would be better than giving an "answer" that does not help you.